# Using a theorem of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

*Theorem.* Let $f\colon\left[ a,b\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Then $f'(x)$ attains all values between $f'(a)$ and  $f'(b)$.

In which questions can I use the theorem? Why is the theorem important?

Comment: For one thing, this shows that any function that does not attain intermediate values cannot have an antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

The result you are asking about is known as the **Intermediate-Value Theorem for Derivatives**.

Let $k \in \mathbb{R}$, and suppose $k$ is between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$. Either $f'(a) < k < f'(b)$ or $f'(b) < k < f'(a)$. Without loss of generality, assume $f'(a) < k < f'(b)$. (The case where $f'(b) < k < f'(a)$ is handled similarly.)

Define $g \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = f(x) - kx$. Then $g$ is differentiable---and thus continuous---on $[a,b]$, and $g'(a) < 0 < g'(b)$. Since $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and since $[a,b]$ is compact, $g$ attains its minimum value at some point $c \in [a,b]$. ***Show that $\boldsymbol{c \in (a,b)}$.*** Then $0 = g'(c) = f'(c) - k$, so $f'(c) = k$. Thus, $f'$ attains the value $k$ at a point in $(a,b)$.

Since $k$ was arbitrary, this proves the assertion.

Comment: You need to show that $c \neq a$ and $c \neq b$. Show that $c \neq a$ by looking at $g'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} [(g(x)-g(a)](x-a)$ first. Then show that $c \neq b$ by looking at $g'(b) = \lim_{x \to b} [(g(x) - g(b)]/(x-b)$.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question....

Comment: The question is not "How do I prove the theorem."

Comment: I see now that it pays to read the question. I'm just now doing it (whoops!). :) Touche!

Comment: The theorem can be used to prove the Inverse Function Theorem. Besides that, I'm not sure how else it is used.

Comment: interesting, I did not know that